# Prove that $X,Y$ are independent random variables $\iff$ $F(x,y)=F_{X}(x)\cdot F_{Y}(y)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

My professor proved it but I tried to give my own proof, because what wrote my professor it's unclear to me. This is the proposition to prove:

> Prove that $X,Y$ are independent random variables $\iff$ $F(x,y)=F_{X}(x)\cdot F_{Y}(y)$.

My proof:

> **($\Rightarrow$)** $X, Y$ are independent random variables. Then:
>
> $\mathbb{P}${$X\leq x$, $Y \leq y\}=\mathbb{P}${$X\leq x$}$\cdot \mathbb{P}\{Y \leq y\}=\mathbb{P}${$X\in (-\infty ,x]$}$\cdot \mathbb{P}\{Y\in (-\infty ,y]\} $
>
> $\implies F(x,y)=F_{X}(x)\cdot F_{Y}(y),$ because $(-\infty ,x]$ and $(-\infty ,y]$ are borelians of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> **($\Leftarrow$)** Let $B_1, B_2$ be borelians of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> We want to see that $ \mathbb{P}${$X\in B_1$, $Y \in B_2\}=\mathbb{P}\{X\in B_1\} \cdot\mathbb{P}\{ Y \in B_2\}.$

I don't know how to follow from here, how to see it formally. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the other way we want to see? $\mathbb{P}\{X\in B_1\} \cdot\mathbb{P}\{ Y \in B_2\} = \mathbb{P}\{X\in B_1,Y \in B_2\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can argue similar way that if $F(x,y) = F_X(x) F_Y(y)$ then $\mathbb{P}[x \le x, Y \le y] = \mathbb{P}[X \le x] \mathbb{P}[Y \le y]$. Isn't this equivalent to being independent?

Comment: We have to see it for every borelian in $\mathbb{R}$, doing it in this way, you can only see that it's true for $(-\infty ,x]$ and $(-\infty ,y]$.

Comment: @Abrahamlure Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)) only defines in terms of these $(-\infty,x]$ sets

Comment: Saying that the above is true for every $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$ would work?

Comment: @Abrahamlure i think that's the idea. Not sure how to prove independence on every Borel set, though it should follow